# Access Java object in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, debugging, tomcat, csrf

I have some JSP code I'm trying to modify.

I have a user object that holds and generates a CSRF values. Currently, this value is set at the start of the application and remains constant throughout the application. I have to change this such that it resets each time a new page is accessed.

The code currently is

```
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
      var csrfTokenName = 'csrfValue';
      var csrfTokenValue = '${user.csrfValue}'; //user is the object, which also contains a setCsrfValue() method that generates the CSRF value
      var csrfParam = {csrfValue : csrfTokenValue};
    function csrfUrl(url) {
      if (url.indexOf('?') == -1) {
//setCSRF code here
         return url+'?'+csrfTokenName+'='+csrfTokenValue;
       } else {
//setCSRF code here
               return url+'&'+csrfTokenName+'='+csrfTokenValue;  
               }
    }   

    </script>
```

I tried adding this

```
<%
User user = (User) session.getAttribute('user'); //fixed typo
%>
```

In the script but the page won't load (on that note, is there a tool/setting for debugging JSP, using STS with Tomcat and Firefox)

How do I reference this object correctly so that I can call setCsrfValue();

I tried the following but the page didn't load

```
<%
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute('user'); //fixed typo
user.setCsrfValue();

    %>
```

Comment: try `User user = (User) session.getAttribute('user');`

Comment: I've updated the question as I may not have been clear. I already attempted to add that code in the csrfUrl() function in the script tags.

Comment: Do you get any exception? What do you mean when you say that the page doesnt load?

Comment: An error occurred at line: 33 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/tiles/ContentLayout.jsp
User cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: have you SET the User as attribute to the session?

Comment: I can access the user object using ${user.csrfValue} already so the object is definitely present.

Comment: what is at line 33 of ContentLayout.jsp?

Comment: It's the User user = (User) session.getAttribute('user); line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75787/discussion-between-mavroscy-and-chris-obrien).